# How to import a SDF file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compact-framework, import, sdf

I started using a Sql Compact version of my DB and during the development it occured that the DB needs to be accessible over the network. 
Cause I wasn't able to find a way to share the SDF file over net without replication I need to import it into SQL Server 2008 (Express).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem. GvS's advice gave the keywords to search for:
http://bembengarifin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/08/generate-script-export-data-from-sql-ce.html

Answer (score 2):

CodePlex has a couple of tools now which perfectly address this question.

These are IDE extensions.

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio Express or higher, get [this one.](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/)

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 Pro or higher, get [this one.](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is harder as it looks, because it doesn't seem to work with the SQL Server Import and Export wizard.

You could write a small program, that gets all data from your SDF file table by table/record by record, and then inserts them into the SQL database.

Comment: I also want the schema of the tables not just their content.
If I could just convert the sdf tables into sql...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking out to see if you could use ODBC to directly access the database file, but apparently, no... According to [this forum thread](http://www.mydatabasesupport.com/forums/ms-sqlserver/216820-odbc-driver-sql-ce.html) your best bet is to try to access it through OLEDB/ADO.